# Cron not working in Whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm trying to use a gem whenever on my rails application, it seems like its not working because I created a task in my model and defined a method that just prints out the time.
whenever I try to run whenever `-i` it gives me the following error

```
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/whenever-0.6.2/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `initialize': undefined method `>' for :environment:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

I don't know if I might be doing something wrong when I setup the gem. I am testing it on development environment

My code is as follows

```
schedule.rb


  every 1.minutes do
    runner "Sale.unverified_notifications" , :environment > :development
  end
```

and my model is as follows

```
   def self.unverified_notifications
     logger.info Time.now.to_s
   end
```

Please I need to know if I may be doing something wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: :environment > :development doesn't exist. What do you want with this syntax ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
every 1.minutes do
    runner "Sale.unverified_notifications" , :environment => :development
  end
```

Seems better :)

Comment: Thanks Shingara, it was a typing error that i have noticed but forgot to update to the forum. it works very nice now.